# If $B\subset A\subset \mathbb{R}, A,B$ are uncountable, then $A-B$ is Uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I think this assertion is false and use this counterexample.

To start, let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rationals and $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of prime numbers.

Let $A=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$.  Define $C\subset A$ where $C=\{\sqrt{x}|x\in \mathbb{P}\}$.  Finally, let $B=A-C$.

Since $\mathbb{P}$ is countable, $C$ is countable.  As a side note, we can show by contradiction that $B$ is uncountable since if it were countable, since $C\subset A$, then $A=(A-C)\cup C$ can be written as a countable union, then $A$ would also be countable).  Therefore we have that $A,B$ are uncountable and $C$ is countable.

Now, $A-B=(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})-[(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})-C]=C$  This shows that the above claim is false as a counterexample has been shown.

Is this a valid proof?

EDIT:  Are there any simpler proofs?

Comment: Could it be that $A - B$ doesn't denote the set difference but rather the set $\{ a - b : a \in A, b \in B\}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $A-B$ ?

Comment: You could have thought of simpler counterexample, such as $(0,1) \subset (0,1) \cup \{2\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ (provided that by $\subset$ you mean it cannot be equal sets).

Comment: Okay: $A-B=\{x|x\in A and x\not\in B\}$

Comment: Yes, @Jack, i was trying to show the title assertion is false

Comment: The best counter-example is $A = B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much simpler example is to say $A=\Bbb R, B=\Bbb R - \{0\}$, where $A-B$ has only one element.  If you insist that your inclusions be strict, delete $\{1\}$ from both sets.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a valid counterexample.